Are there programs which compute integrals in $\mathbb{R}^n$?
I look for a software which computes integrals like, for example, this one:
$$\int_{B_R}\frac{|x|^3 dx}{(\varepsilon^2+|x|^2)^{n-1}},$$
where $\varepsilon>0$ and $R>0$ are not specific numbers like $1$ or $\pi,$ $B_R$ is the ball centered in the origin of radius $R$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $n$ is a non-specific natural number.
PS. I ask this because we have lots of programs which compute integrals with specific numbers in $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3,$ but not in an arbitrary $\mathbb{R}^n.$
I really appreciate any answers in advance.

Use polar coordinates. This is the integral on the radial component.

Thank you for your answer. I know how to calculate it. It's just an example, for in Geometric Analysis, we have tons of integrals of this kind and a software which can compute these would be of great help.

I think WolframAlpha is the best in symbolic calculus. If they can't do it you probably need to ask them for further info on packages.
